# How do I send HBAR to an Account on Hedera?

Tags: hedera-hashgraph

I've been trying to send hbar to an account and I get this error, what am I doing wrong?

```js
 await new TransferTransaction()
        .addHbarTransfer(AccountId.fromString("0.0.XXXXXXXX"), new Hbar(1))
        .execute(client);
```

But it fails with this error:

```bash
PrecheckStatusError: transaction 0.0.xxxxxxx@1677810990.286133522 failed precheck with status INVALID_ACCOUNT_AMOUNTS
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Hedera, you need to specify both sending and receiving account. The total sum of amounts in a transaction must be 0.

```
const sendHbar = await new TransferTransaction()
 .addHbarTransfer(sendingAccountId, Hbar.fromTinybars(-1)) //Sending account
 .addHbarTransfer(receivingAccountId, Hbar.fromTinybars(1)) //Receiving account
 .execute(client);
```

Please take a look at the following link for more info
https://docs.hedera.com/hedera/getting-started/transfer-hbar